# trying to use spring 3 but auto wired objects are null (on tomcat)

Tags: spring, tomcat7, autowired

I am trying to do my first steps using spring, but I don't manage to get it working, I would appreciate your assistance.

I am using tomcat and I have added to tomcat lib directory a file: jdbc-service.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


<context:spring-configured />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject"/>

<context:property-placeholder location="database.properties"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

I have a database.properties that defines several properties to be used to obtain DataSource object.
I also have a class that uses @Configuration and it takes the properties for the DB.
In addition i have another @Configuration class that inherits from the first one and added JdbcTemplate object each method is annotated @Bean.

I created an interface UserRepository and an implementation for this called UserRepositoryImpl - which has an annotated @Autowired member JdbcTemplate and implementation of only one method findById inherited from the interface UserRepository.

I have another interface called UserManager and it's implementation UserManagerImpl - which is annotated as @Service, it has a member UserRepository annotated with @Autowired.
it is implementing a method to findById and just tried to get the user from the DB using the UserRepository.

Last, I have a servlet that uses a member

```
@Autowired
private UserManager userManager;
```

the problem is that userManager is null. I think that the spring does not get initiated, but i don't know why. I am probably missing something important.

Please help me as I can't progress.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Servlets are not Spring beans. They're instantiated by tomcat directly, and not by Spring. They are thus out of Spring's scope and can't be injected.

Consider using Spring MVC controllers instead of servlets.

Comment: I don't want to use Spring MVC controller as I want to add this to an existing project. There is no way to use it? Also, I tried to execute the same behavior in a main class where the spring projects is, but also I get null. I think I am missing something about how to load the Spring. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your UserManagerImpl is in package `com.myproject` which is specified as base package?

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your reply. The class UserManagerImpl is in the package but not directly. It is com.myproject.user.service.impl.UserManagerImpl. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: set your base-package as com.myproject.*

Comment: OK, I will try. Isn't there a way I need to notify the servlet to load all the spring context? (including all beans). I got here an answer that servlet is not a spring object hence i can't inject using @Autowire a spring bean into it and I must use Spring MVC which i can't currently use. Thank you very much again :)

Comment: That's true...Servlet is not a spring object/bean.You can achieve same functionality as servlet by using Spring Controller also. Consider using it.

Comment: OK, but if I still use regular servlet, I can't use the spring services that I described here? I can't wire a spring service into my servlet? Thanks.

Comment: you can try load time weaver for this.Google it for it's example.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml specify two context listeners but make sure the first listener is Spring's:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```